# How do I run function on exit python vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a discord.py bot I'm running on vscode and I'm trying to save data whenever I terminate it, the problem is I always terminate using the big red stop button built in vscode and I can't figure out what exit code it is to trigger a function when I press it

Comment: Look at the `atexit` module in the standard library.

Comment: I tried using it, didn't work with the button :(

Comment: I'd suggest running this differently, or structuring your code differently for how you manage persistence if you are going to continue to run this via VSCode. For Python programs, VSCode sends a `SIGKILL` to your program when you hit the big red stop button, which is not a signal that can be caught and handled. It will also prevent registered `atexit` methods from working.